# Anime movie involving people exploding into monsters?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've watched an anime movie a few years ago where people are turning into monsters (because of inbalanced magic?). The main character hunts them with the same magic and wears a suit of armor that compresses his body to keep him from turning into a monster himself. I could have sworn it was call Steins;Gate, but it turns out that it is not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Strait Jacket](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2311880/), (2008).

> In a world where sorcery and science co-exist, the power of magic
>   comes with a price: Humans who do not take proper precautions are
>   transformed into horrific demons. Those who destroy these demons - and
>   run the highest risk of all - are tactical sorcerists known as Strait
>   Jackets.

It was shown as one of the Sci Fi Channel's Ani-Monday features.

Comment: Thank was totally it, thanks! I could not remember it for the life of me!